# Z-index Not Working With Positioning

Tags: css, position, z-index

I have searched for this topic but nothing seems to be helping me with my issue.

I have a search function that drops down when you start typing but it drops behind the menu bar hiding the search results.
I have played with the z-indexes but nothing helps.

I read that z-index doesn't work for certain positions. Is this true? If so how can I get the results to display over the menu bar?

If I change the positions my menu jumps out of place.

The css for the results:

```
#results {
z-index: 10000;
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
float: right;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: left;
```

the css for the menu:

```
.menu {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 900px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 17px;
z-index: 3;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
```

Thanks!

Comment: post your site link or html code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you show us your HTML codes ( related parts ) as well ?

Comment: Why are you using position and float? Use one or the other, decide!

Comment: The site was done by a previous company. They did the coding and we have never had a chance to change it.
The site is collegesa.co.za, the coding is very messy I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.menu2` has a `z-index` of `3`, `.banner` (who is a parent to your search dropdown) needs to have a higer `z-index` (the class names are from [collegesa.co.za](http://collegesa.co.za/)).

Try to set `z-index` to `4` for `.banner`

```
.banner {
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I couldn't work out where it needed to be as the code is all over the place.